# net use - Causing Echo Redirect to Fail

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a script that successfully scans a specified directory for a list of files, copies the files to a destination folder and generates a log of all files not found in the source. I had to alter this script to include `net use` in order to map a network drive. Since doing so the script no longer generates the error log as it did before.

I'm very new to this and can't find any information on why this may be happening. Can somebody please help?

```
@echo off
pause
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

net use U: \\abc\def

SET "src="U:\Source Folder""
SET "dst=C:\Destination Folder"
SET "file_list=C:\files.txt"
SET "out=.\errors.log"
echo > %out%

FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%f IN ("%file_list%") DO (
    rem just searching to find out existense of file
    WHERE /Q /R %src% "%%f"
    IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (
        FOR /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%s IN (`WHERE /R %src% "%%f"`) DO (
            echo "%%s => %dst%\%%f" >> %out%
            @copy /y "%%s" "%dst%\%%f" 
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo %%f >> %out%
    )
)
```

Comment: The log file will be created in the current Working Directory which should be wherever your batch file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo %%f >> %out%` with `set /p out=%%f`

[Edit]
Sorry I misunderstood your question.

Is it because you have two quotation marks in all of the drive path set?

As in replace
 
`SET "src="U:\Source Folder""`

With

`SET src="U:\Source Folder"`

Comment: Thank you. Your solution successfully creates the error log among other positive things, but it does not store the file names of the missing files in the error log. I tried adding >> %out% but that definitely did not help. Would you mind showing me how I can get the missing files printed into the generated log file?

Comment: @Swift, not understanding why you would recommend this solution.

Comment: In response to your question. If you think, now you have a variable called %out% and so you can put that into a file in a number of ways. `echo %out% >> "Path_to_log" `